# Regarding login and register page asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to change the default theme of Asp.net.I changed it but now the problem is whenever i click on the login button or register button on the navbar it shows on the home page instead of showing it on a different page.I tired figuring out where the problem was coming from here's what i gathered so far

```
<!--This Is Causing That Problem-->
<Section id="TextHeader">
      <div class="container px-0">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12" id="special">
                  <h1 class="text-center text-white">Content</h1>
                  <h5>Content</h5>
                  <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill" href="About us.html">Get Started</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </Section>

  <Section id="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12" id="hulky">
                  <h3 class="text-center">Why Us</h3>
                  <hr>
                  <p class="text-center">
                      content
                  </p>
                  <a href="Get Started.html" class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill">Get Started</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </Section>



      <section id="Middle">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <h3 class="text-center">Content</h3>
                      <hr>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </section>
      <section id="unamed">
          <DIV class="container-fluid px-0">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <img src="Teacher.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid d-none d-lg-block">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <h4>Content</h4>
                      <p id="teacher">Content</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </DIV>
      </section>


      <section id="Students">
          <DIV class="container-fluid px-0">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <img src="Student.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid d-none d-lg-block">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <h1>Content>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </DIV>
      </section>
```

this code has something that is causing the problem and this is default bootstrap code so its very tough to know what is causing the problem